# "for-loop" to reduce coding on Chisel3.2

Tags: chisel

I want to code with for-loop for redundant part.

Coding.

```
//Priority Encoder
class P_Encoder(NumInputs: UInt) extends Module {
    val io = new Bundle {
        val Req[NumInputs]          = Bool(INPUT)                   //Requests
        val Rls[NumInputs]          = Bool(INPUT)                   //Releases
        val Grant[NumInputs]        = UInt(OUTPUT(log(NumInputs)))  //Grants
    }

    val cnt = 0
    for (i<-0 to NumInputs-1) {
        when (io.Req[i] & !io.Rls[i]) {
            cnt         := cnt + 1.W
            io.Grant[i] = cnt
        }
        else {
            io.Grant[i] = 0.W
        }
    }
}
```

I want to code using "for-loop" to code redundant part.

Comment: I’m not sure I quite understand your question here, but the `when` construct, which basically creates a Mux, requires an `otherwise` clause instead of the `else` keyword.

Comment: thanx to fix, yes ot should be.otherwsise. and cnd should be va; count = Reg(UInt(5)) for example.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few minor issues with this code:

- Generally we name variables starting with a lower-case letter in Scala, this is primarily style, but it does have semantic meaning it certain circumstances (like pattern matching)
- Square brackets are only used for type parameters (like Java generics), indexing uses normal parentheses in Scala
- An input Vec of Bools is normally defined as: `val req  = Input(Vec(numInputs, Bool()))` (assuming `import chisel3._`, but this should also work in `Chisel._` for Chisel 3.2)
- `if` and `else` are used for static parameterization (ie. at hardware elaboration time) while `when` and `.otherwise` are used for dynamic logic (eg. actual muxes)
- `UInt` is for hardware types, if you have a static parameter (like `numInputs`), use a Scala `Int`

Other than the minor syntactical stuff, the trickiest part of getting this code right is understanding the difference between Scala constructs that are only run at *elaboration* time (ie. when the Scala program generates the hardware), vs. what actually shows up in the hardware. I would suggest reading this thread from the chisel-users mailing list for some more context about some of this stuff: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/chisel-users/gRoNnH-Y5hE/ynDCtmNPCAAJ

I'm a little confused as to what value `io.grant` is supposed to get, but I'm assuming it should be the index of the highest priority `io.req`.
Here's an untested version of your code that I *think* should work and do what you want:

```scala
//Priority Encoder
class P_Encoder(numInputs: Int) extends Module {
    // We wrap ports in IO
    val io = IO(new Bundle {
        val req        = Input(Vec(numInputs, Bool()))
        val rls        = Input(Vec(numInputs, Bool()))
        val grant      = Output(UInt(log2Up(numInputs).W))
    })
    io.grant := 0.U // default grant value
    // Due to Chisel last connect semantics, the last connection wins
    // Thus the highest index will have priority
    for (i <- 0 to numInputs - 1) {
        when (io.req(i) && !io.rls(i)) {
            io.grant := i.U
        }
    }
}
```

This code is tricky because it's mixing an elaboration time `for` loop with hardware `when`s and connections, I'm going to manually unroll this loop to illustrate what it's doing:

```scala
    io.grant := 0.U
    when (io.req(0) && !io.rls(0)) {
        io.grant := 0.U
    }
    when (io.req(1) && !io.rls(1)) {
        io.grant := 1.U
    }
    when (io.req(2) && !io.rls(2)) {
        io.grant := 2.U
    }
    ...
```

Alternatively, we can just reuse the built-in PriorityEncoder utility if we want

```scala
import chisel3.util.PriorityEncoder
val enables = io.req.zip(io.rls).map { case (x, y) => x && !y }
// PriorityEncoder gives priority to *lowest* order bit
io.grant := PriorityEncoder(enables)
```

Comment: I wat is ```val grant        = Output(Vec(numInputs, UInt()))``` and ```io.grant(i) := i```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with everything @jkoenig says. 
In an another example assuming Jack's IO structure, there are times I like
using `foldLeft` combined with `when`/`elsewhen`

```
io.rel.zip(io.req).zipWithIndex.foldLeft(when(false.B){}) { case (lastWhen,((req, rel), index)) =>
    lastWhen.elsewhen(req && !rel) {
      io.grant := index.U
    }
  } otherwise {
    io.grant := 0.U
  }
```

`when` and `elsewhen` both return a `WhenClause` which can be used with foldLeft to keep adding clauses.